# Экспорт графика из MSChart в векторный формат изображения. C#, WimForms

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Доброго времени суток. Ребята, мне нужна помощь с выгрузкой графика без потери качества. У меня в программе создаются графики в компоненте MS Chart с большим количеством данных. Мне необходимо осуществить выгрузку построенного графика в векторный формат изображения.

```
    SaveFileDialog SD = new SaveFileDialog();
    SD.FileName = "test";
    if (SD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string path = SD.FileName + ".emf";
        SaveImage(path, ImageFormat.Emf);
    }
```

График выгружается в созданный файл, но качество графика оставляет желать лучшего.
Это то, что я вижу в программе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это получаю в emf файле, при открытии в Paint:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это получаю в emf файле, при открытии в CorelDraw:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что же делать?

Comment: а по-моему вполне достойно.. что именно вас смущает?

Comment: @4per ведь сетка у меня другая в программе, а тут все одним стилем

Comment: а это не может быть следствием ограничений самого emf-формата? просто предположение

Comment: @rdorn пробовала делать формат wmf, та же ситуация..

Comment: вики утверждает https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile что EMF более навороченный, а чем открываете результат? многие программы предварительно делают растеризацию EMF и отображают уже результат. Может в этом проблема

Comment: @rdorn открываю paint-ом

Comment: @rdorn действительно, открыла OpenOffice Draw, результат намного лучше. Просто у меня есть несколько wmf файлов, система по умолчанию открывает их в paint, и у них все отлично с графикой (но это конечно файлы не из моей программы)

Comment: ну естественно, Paint - растровый редактор, поэтому он сначала делает растеризацию. Попробуйте вставить тоже изображение но с высоким разрешением, получите более четкие результаты, но лучше конечно открывать вектор специальным софтом. InkScape попробуйте из бесплатных

Comment: @rdorn, мучаюсь уже не первый день, я открываю emf с помощью CorelDraw. Когда строю график на MSChart я рисую мелкую сетку с помощью точечной линии, а CorelDraw воспринимает точки в линии как кружочки, поэтому сетка жирная кажется. Как сделать так, чтобы линия была именно точечная, а не подряд идущие объекты-кружки?

Comment: вот этого честно говоря не знаю, скорее всего это особенность хранения таких линий в самом EMF или последствия конвертации в EMF из GDI+ Graphics. Тут нужно тонкости формата знать, одной эрудиции мало. Попробуйте спросить на EnSO если язык позволяет.

Comment: да, в сети на EMF основательно ругаются на обоих языках, а вам он собственно для чего? не проще будет за кадром увеличить размеры контрола и снять с него BMP с высоким разрешением? понимаю что костыль, просто как вариант

Comment: @rdorn, необходима именно векторная графика для дальнейшего открытия именно в CorelDraw, потому что бывают случаи, когда пользователю нужно вручную поправить график.

Comment: тогда вам нужен скорее совет опытного дизайнера, а не программиста, чтобы побороть EMF. Или строить графики другими средствами, которые позволяют экспорт в более удобный формат вместо EMF.